# functors determined by associated bimodules

Tags: ct.category-theory, derived-categories

When is a Ch-enriched (enriched over the category of chain complexes) functor $F: A \to B$ determined by the bimodule $A^{op} \otimes B \to Ch_{dg}$, $(a,b) \mapsto Hom_B(F(a),b)$. Or in general how much of $F$ do we remember? This might be standard stuff but would like a reference.

Comment: What do you mean by a Ch-enriched functor?

Comment: Presumably, a functor enriched in the category of chain complexes.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, then the answer is "always" by the enriched Yoneda lemma, section 2.4 in Kelly's "Basic concepts of enriched category theory".